# Do we really need all these 1000 threads running?

Tags: multithreading

Using the fancy new taskmanager in windows 8 i noticed something that for me came as a suprise, the currently used/running threads where around 1k.

Since ive just resonantly touched the tutorials and theory behind multithreading software and games. I got the assumption that if you wanted to get the best performance out of your software, you should always have at least one thread per logical processor when there is work to be done. Since that processor would otherwise be "unused".

But seeing as i am already running around 1000 threads, wont all processors be working on something already?

Why multithread if the processing power is already being used by the other 50 or so processes?
Wont managing all these 1000 threads take cpu enough?
Why should i as a programmer handle the threads and not the operative system? If it gives each process one thread, wouldn't my software still be "multhithreaded"?.

Is using more threads just a fancier way of prioritizing processes?

Comment: Are you sure those 1000 threads are actually running (i.e. using CPU cycles) as oppose to just present?  It's not uncommon to have a lot of threads that are sleeping, and only wake up when there is some work for them to do.

Comment: Hundreds/thousands of threads automatically bad = FUD.  I have 67 processes and 1135 threads at the moment.  CPU usage 1-2%.  Everything is working fine.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'd say, probably not. Although this question is a bit rhetorical, take a look at this article/book excerpt, by Jeffrey Richter, [Stop the madness](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2011/03/25/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-4-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx) (from the book [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667454)). It discusses just those things you ask.

> If all we cared about was raw performance, then the optimum number of threads to have 
>   on any machine is identical to the number of CPUs on that machine. [...] All threads still have a kernel object, kernel-mode stack, 
>   and other resources allocated to them. This trend of creating threads willy-nilly because they 
>   are cheap has to stop; threads are not cheap—rather, they are expensive, so use them wisely.

I highly recommend that book. Well worth reading front to back, although it is fairly big, ~900 pages.

Multi-threading though is a *very complex* subject and cannot be easily answered in just a few lines, it is highly dependent on what you are trying to achieve. As always, it depends and you have to measure/evaluate/optimize any solution to get optimal performance. However, just routinely dishing out threads is probably not a good idea in general. As a side note, a managed thread allocates 1 MB stack memory, meaning that creating (and holding on to) threads in a .NET application can be very wasteful.

Also, just because a tread *exists* does *not* mean that it is consuming a full core. It *may* do some work, but it may also sit idle and wait for some work to come along (which is the most likely case, otherwise your overall CPU consumption would constantly be closer to 100 than 0). They *do* however consume, or more correct, waste system resources.

Introducing threads adds a significant amount of extra complexity to your application, even though many techniques are being introduced to make them easier to use (various parallel frameworks etc.). The underlying complexity is still there though, sometimes posing as harmless, but always ready to burst out into its true nature (timing issues, deadlocks, debugging complexity etc).

In short you might say, "Do not use multiple thread unless you have a reason to".
Even then, t(h)read lightly.

Comment: Thank you for the informative response. It was meant to be rhetorical to raise some arguments and to gain counter ones. The article you link was right on and is definitively a keeper to use in any debate. And I'm also glad i could milk a bit more out of your answer! ;). I will not chose your answer YET. Since I´m interested to see if there will be anyone with the counter opinion.

Comment: Having the number of threads match the number of CPUs might be optimal in programs that never need to wait for I/O [either waiting for I/O operations to complete, or waiting for external events to occur, notice of which would occur via I/O].  Given that many pieces of code will need to wait for things to happen at times when their internal state is rather complicated, using threads to manage such things is helpful.

Comment: @supercat Agreed, especially for things like network traffic. And in such cases, "you have a reason to" ;-)

Comment: Just a quick node: `..a managed thread allocates 1 MB stack memory, meaning that creating (and holding on to) threads in a .NET application can be very wasteful` that is true for threads in general, BUT the space is only reserved, not actually allocated. Stack space is allocated per-page (plus one guard page). You waste virtual memory, but on x64 is not that relevant

Comment: On x86 however you run out of (virtual) memory with a ~1k threads (per process, obviously)

Answer (score 8):

I like Jokob answer and I feel that most of the important points have been already made:

- 1k threads (globally) does not mean they are fully running: they may be ALL sitting around waiting
- In general, thinking about the *global* number of threads in a system is very misleading (see clarification below)
- Threads are (not only) used for parallel programming: they are used in situations where you need more than one line of execution (when you block waiting for a network answer, for example, but you still need to update the UI and keep it responsive, or when you have low priority tasks (spell check, code inspections,...) in the same process, ...). After all, threads existed and where useful long before multicore CPUs!
- Now however we often see "madness": too many threads. This is not new: one of first cases where the early network (web?) servers: one thread per-connection (!). Stupid, wasteful. We went on, and we now use threadpools (and more refined things too, like I/O completion ports) and (more recently) asynchronous programming.

However, even in the case of threadpools, the number of threads is per-process (unless you use the system threadpool, available from Windows2000 onward); therefore if you have 50 processes each wanting to take the greatest advantage from a 4 core system, you have globally a reasonable number of 200 threads (and, usually, threadpools have their optimum around 2X number of cores, to take I/O block and wait into account).

This is natural, you have to think per process, not OS wide. Think about what would happen if you use a centralized threadpool with a hard limit, for all processes. Suppose one application takes all of them: what choice do you have? No, you cannot have a hard, OS wide limit. Each application is basically on its own. This is the model enforce by "modern" (1990-era) OSes based on segregate processes and virtual, private address space, like NT and Linux: you are alone in the OS, and should not care about the others (sometimes this is strongly enforced, like in the case of memory)

Comment: +1 for "you are on your own, don't give anything about the others" !

Answer (score 0):

To be simple, operating system makes all applications feel like they are running on a machine (computer) of their own. For example a 32 bit application theoretically has 4GB of memory while physical computer has 2 GB. The os is using techniques like time sharing multiplexing to provide this. With this mechanism you can observe this 1K threads. (I saw 72K on a terminal server with 28 users connected.) Since creating threads are expensive programmers create threads for once and they make them sleep when the task is done via a mechanism like mutex, semaphore ...

That's because you see lots of threads and 1% CPU usage. If you want to see how much CPU resource the thread used check out the CPU time for thread or application. This gives more clues about what is happening.